# jQuery/PHP form submit unintended behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to create a form, where all fields have to be filled in, before it can be successfully submitted.

So, for example, I have some logic, where, if an error occurs, the error counter increments and if the counter doesn't equal 0, then the form doesn't submit and an alert box appears, telling the user that there are some empty fields that need filling. **That is the intended behaviour**. However, when I try to submit it again, it successfully submits, even though there are errors.

If it makes it easier, here's the temporary URL for the web page in question: http://176.32.230.49/cecc.co.uk/add-season.php

Here is my code:

jQuery (the code in question)

```
$("#season-submit").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var errorFree = 0;
       //var competitionEntries = $(".text-box").val();
       // if ($("#season-form").find(competitionEntries).val() == "") {
           // competitionEntries.val("Illegals"); 
            $(".text-box").each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == "" && !($(this).siblings(".error-box").is(":visible"))) {

                    var fieldName = $(this).siblings(".error-box").attr("id");
                    fieldName = fieldName.substr(0, fieldName.indexOf('-')); 
                    fieldName = fieldName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + fieldName.slice(1);

                    //console.log($(this).siblings(".error-box").attr("id"));
                    if (fieldName == "Competition") {
                        $(this).siblings(".error-box").text("Which " + fieldName + "?").slideDown();
                        errorFree++;
                    } else {
                        $(this).siblings(".error-box").text("Please enter " + fieldName + "...").slideDown();
                        errorFree++;
                    }
                } else if ($(this).val() != "" && $(this).siblings(".error-box").is(":visible")) {

                    $(this).siblings(".error-box").slideUp();

                }

            });

            $(".dpt").each(function() {
                var dateTimeValue = $(this).val();

                if (dateTimeValue.length == 16 && isValid(dateTimeValue)) {

                    var day = parseFloat(dateTimeValue.substring(0,2));

                    var month = parseFloat(dateTimeValue.substring(3,5)) - 1;

                    var year = parseFloat(dateTimeValue.substring(6,10));

                    var hour = parseFloat(dateTimeValue.substring(11,13));

                    var minute = parseFloat(dateTimeValue.substring(14,16));

                    dateTimeValue = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute);

                } else {
                    errorFree++;
                    $(this).siblings(".error-box").text("Stop trying to be clever...").slideDown();
                }



            });
            if (errorFree == 0) {
                    $("#season-form").submit();
                } else {
                    console.log("Ride this way...");
                    alert("Not all entries are valid. Please correct them.");
                }

        //span2 dpt
      //  }
   // $("#season-form").find(competitionEntries).val("Illegals"); 
        console.log("Oh, she wasn't");
    });
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
        <title>CECC | Add Season</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexnav.css"  type="text/css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/foundation-datepicker.css" />
        <link href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/foundation-icons.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body class="can-add-season">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="banner" class="clearfix">

                        <img id="crest" src="images/cecc-logo2.png" />
                        <h1>Cadmore End Cricket Club</h1>
            </div>


            <nav class="clearfix">
                <div class="menu-button">Menu</div>
                <ul class="flexnav" data-breakpoint="800">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">News</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Social Events</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item-with-ul">
                        <a href="#">Team</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Players</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fixtures/Results</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Statistics</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
           </nav> 
            <main>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-12 columns">
                        <h1 class="main-header text-center">Add Player</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-12 columns">
                        <p class="standard-text text-center">You can add a new Cricket season on this web page. To add more fixtures to the season, click on the button below and a new fixture form will appear.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form id="season-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process-season.php" method="post">
                    <div class="fixture">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="small-12 medium-2 medium-offset-5 columns end">
                                <label>Season
                                    <select name="season">
                                        <option value="option-1" selected><?php echo intval(date("Y")) . "/" . intval(date("Y")+1); ?></option>
                                        <option value="option-2"><?php echo intval(date("Y")+1) . "/" . intval(date("Y")+2); ?></option>
                                        <option value="option-3"><?php echo intval(date("Y")+2) . "/" . intval(date("Y")+3); ?></option>
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="error-box"></div>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
                                <h3 class="fixture-number">Fixture #1</h3>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
                                <label>Date and Time
                                    <input readonly id="date-time-box" type="text" class="span2 dpt" name="match-dt[]" value="<? echo date("d/m/Y"); ?> 12:00">
                                    <div id="date-time-error-1" class="error-box"></div>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                                <label>Team
                                    <select name="team-division[]">
                                        <option value="team-1">1st Team</option>
                                        <option value="team-2">2nd Team</option> 
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="error-box"></div>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                                <label>Competition
                                    <input id="competition-input" class="text-box" name="competition[]" type="text" />
                                    <div id="competition-error-1" class="error-box"></div>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="small-12 medium-2 columns">
                                <label>Home/Away
                                    <select name="location[]">
                                        <option value="home">Home</option>
                                        <option value="away">Away</option> 
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="error-box"></div>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
                                <label>Opponents
                                    <input id="opposition-input" class="text-box" name="opposition[]" type="text" />
                                    <div id="opposition-error-1" class="error-box"></div>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
                                <label>Venue
                                    <input id="venue-input" class="text-box" name="venue[]" type="text" />
                                    <div id="venue-error-1" class="error-box"></div>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="test"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="small-12 columns end">
                                <img id="fixture-addition-logo" src="images/netvibes.png" class="float-right" />
                                <a id="fixture-addition-text" class="float-right">Add New Fixture</a>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="submit-season-container" class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-4 medium-offset-4 columns end">
                           <!-- <input type="submit" name="create-season" id="season-submit" class="button expanded radius success" value="Submit New Season" /> -->
                            <button id="season-submit" class="button expanded radius success">Submit New Season</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </main>
            <footer class="clearfix">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="medium-4 columns">
                        <p class="float-left"><?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
                                echo $fname . " " . $lname . " <a href='logout.php'>(Sign Out)</a>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<a href='login.php'>Login</a>";
                            }?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="medium-3 columns text-center">
                        <p>&copy; 2016 <a href="<?php 
                            echo $potentialBeginning; ?>">Potential Beginning</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="medium-5 columns">
                        <p class="float-right"><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></p>
                        <p class="float-right"><a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </footer>
        </div>
        <script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/what-input.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexnav.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/locales/foundation-datepicker.en-GB.js"></script>
        <script src="js/datepicker/foundation-datepicker.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an errorFree increment only if error-box is not visbile. I think that's the reason of why 2nd time you submit it doesn't increment errorFree and why the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by this condition:

```
$(this).val() == "" && !($(this).siblings(".error-box").is(":visible"))
```

The first time you click submit, if the value is empty and `.error-box` is hidden then you **show** the error and increment `errorFree`. But, next click to submit `.error-box` is already **shown** so even if the value is empty the above condition will not be met:

```
$(this).val() == "" //true
!($(this).siblings(".error-box").is(":visible")) //false
true && false === false
```

I suggest to separate the `show/hide` logic from `empty/filled` logic:

```
if($(this).val() === "") {
   //Slide/show .error-box and increment errors
} else {
  //Hide  .error-box
}
```